# List product attributes using PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes

I am making a new shop template using an old template so as to quickly achieve my needs.

Below is the portion of the code to get the price of a product:

```
<td style="width: 10%;">
<?php
   $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
   echo $product->get_price_html();
?>
</td>
```

I want to achieve something similar, with *product attributes*.

Comment: Besides the function `get_price_html` that you used, there is a function `get_attributes` that you can call. This function should return an array with the attributes which you can loop over.

Comment: So this will make it like `<td style="width: 10%;">
<?php
 $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
 echo $product->get_attribute(attributename?);
 ?>
</td>`

Comment: No, it's `get_attributes` with a `s`. You should then not `echo` the array, but first loop over it with `foreach` for example, like `foreach ($product->get_attributes() as $attribute) { ... }`. Then inside the `foreach` (where the three dots are), you can call `echo $product->get_attribute($attribute);`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to print the product attributes.

```
foreach ($product->get_attributes() as $attribute) {
   echo '<p>'.$product->get_attribute($attribute).'</p>';
}
```